# Unable to view Comments in Public Telegram Channel

Tags: telegram-messenger

Whenever I try to read comments in a telegram channel it says "This channel is private. Please join it to continue viewing its content". But I have already joined the channel and the channel is public. Why do I get this message? I have been playing around with different options available suddenly encountering this issue?

Actually I have removed the user from the channel and then added him again. I remember this issue started from that point. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: On what operating system? Are you using a downloaded version or the web version?

Comment: Tried in Android and also in the downloaded version. Both reports the same error.. This is not happening for the newly added user. If we add the user and then remove them and then if we add again we are encountering this issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but only in one particular channel. All the other channels are fine. I've only tried it in the Android app so far.